# How can i get all rows in a gorm as reflect type slice

Tags: go, go-gorm

I want to write a function that returns all rows in a table using a reflective type.

```
func (rt *tableRouter) select_table_DB(ctx context.Context, vars url.Values, tableType reflect.Type, name string) (reflect.Value, error) {
    db, err := db.Open(rt.dbcfg)
    if err != nil {
        return reflect.Value{}, err
    }
    defer db.Close()

    rows := reflect.MakeSlice(reflect.SliceOf(tableType), 0, 0)
    db.WithContext(ctx).Table(name).Find(&rows)

    return rows, err
}
```

This only returns `{}`

Answer (score 0):

You must provide a concret object (which contains a set of exported fields) to receive data from database so than gorm knows how database table columns map to object members. And `reflect.Value` is not such an object, maybe you could  try to use `reflect.Value.Interface()` which returns an interface whose underlying data is an concret object. By the way, `gorm/gen` is a nice tool to automatically generate CURD code for your model. ([enter link description here](https://github.com/go-gorm/gen))